# Making combinations of row values based on another value in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I need to make a network visualization, and I have data, but not in the correct format yet! The data looks as follows in a dataframe in R:

```
Title       Name
Article1    Johnson
Article1    Hansson
Article1    Michaels
Article2    Nielsson
Article2    Madsen
Article2    Shannon
Article2    Paddington
```

And I would like to find the combination of names based on title - i.e. collaborating authors, so an output in this format

```
Source     Target      Title
Johnson    Hansson     Article1
Johnson    Michaels    Article1
Hansson    Michaels    Article1
Nielsson   Madsen      Article2
Nielsson   Shannon     Article2
Nielsson   Paddington  Article2
Madsen     Shannon     Article2
Madsen     Paddington  Article2
Shannon    Paddington  Article2
```

The network is undirected, so source/target is just column names to illustrate. So how can I do this in R? I'm sure there is a simple way, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, in `base` R:

```
 combos<-tapply(df$Name,df$Title,function(x) t(combn(x,2)))
 cbind(setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,combos)),c("Source","Target")),Title=rep(names(combos),vapply(combos,nrow,1L)))

#    Source     Target    Title
#1  Johnson    Hansson Article1
#2  Johnson   Michaels Article1
#3  Hansson   Michaels Article1
#4 Nielsson     Madsen Article2
#5 Nielsson    Shannon Article2
#6 Nielsson Paddington Article2
#7   Madsen    Shannon Article2
#8   Madsen Paddington Article2
#9  Shannon Paddington Article2
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! It almost works - only thing is, that in stead of the names (Johnson etc.) in the source/target columns, I get numbers.

Comment: Very likely your columns are `factors` (I've tested with `character` vectors). Change `df$Name` with `as.character(df$Name)` in the first line and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table` [v >= 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and the new `tstrsplit` function

```
library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5
setDT(df)[, setNames(tstrsplit(combn(Name, 2, toString, simplify = FALSE), ", "), 
                     c("Source", "Target")), 
          by = Title]
#       Title   Source     Target
# 1: Article1  Johnson    Hansson
# 2: Article1  Johnson   Michaels
# 3: Article1  Hansson   Michaels
# 4: Article2 Nielsson     Madsen
# 5: Article2 Nielsson    Shannon
# 6: Article2 Nielsson Paddington
# 7: Article2   Madsen    Shannon
# 8: Article2   Madsen Paddington
# 9: Article2  Shannon Paddington
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I get the following error message Error in transpose(strsplit(as.character(x), ...), fill = fill, ignore.empty = FALSE) : 
  object 'Ctranspose' not found

Comment: @nicola yours is fine too.

Comment: @tkoz_dk did you install the development version from Github?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Yes. And then I restarted R, and now it works :) Thank you!